# How to read a .class File located either in Local or Distributed File system to a java.lang.Class object in Java?

Tags: java

How to read a .class File located either in Local or Distributed File system to a Class object in Java?

I have a hello.class File in the local file system and in some cases it is in Distributed File System. I have a new application where I want to read the external `hello.class` file and construct a `java.lang.Class` object how do I do that?

Note: My `hello.class` is not in the class path of my Application and I still want to read just like I would read some external text file but I want to construct a `java.lang.Class` object?

Comment: make sure the class in quest in in the java path and then call
`Class.forName(name);`

Comment: Please imagine I cannot add it to classpath instead I want to read .class files dynamically so at runtime

Answer (score -1):

You can use a decomplier like JAD or jd-gui